# When Activated Auto Completion in Eclipse Do not add Suggestion name to variable or object name

Tags: eclipse

I activated auto completion in eclipse for android but when type a name for object like String compiler add "String" end of my name
for example

```
String strNameString
```

Just I want disable this property of auto completion